# How do I copy a value from the last row in a column and pasting it to the first row of a column?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Workbook with two worksheets. Let's call them Worksheet 1 and Worksheet 2. In worksheet 1 I have a column with a variable where I lag the variable (using offset) i times. I save the lag and the R^2 in an array each time. Whenever I lag the variable, I need to paste data from the last row in column B in worksheet 2. As the variable i increases, the row from which I copy the data (worksheet 2) must increase with the same step as i (Eg. For i = 1 to 10) in a negative way (offset(-i) from bottom to top - so I guess the rows must decrease)- Eg. when i = 2, I want to copy the second row from the bottom in worksheet 2 and insert in the top row of worksheet 1.

As i increase, the rows in worksheet 1 are supposed to be offset by 1 so essentially filling/replacing the empty cell in worksheet 1 with the row value in worksheet 2.

I've tried various things, but it does not copy and insert leaving either blank cells or copying one cell in worksheet 2 and pasting it every other row in worksheet 1

```
Sub Regression()
Dim Y, X As Range
Dim MyArray As Variant
Dim AWF As WorksheetFunction
Dim DefaultRate, Data As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

Set AWF = Application.WorksheetFunction
Set DefaultRate = Workbooks("Main sheet.xlsm").Sheets("DefaultRate")
Set Data = Workbooks("Main sheet.xlsm").Sheets("Data")

Set Y = DefaultRate.Range("B2:B55")
Set X = DefaultRate.Range("D2:D55")

ReDim MyArray(5, 5)

For i = LBound(MyArray, 1) To UBound(MyArray, 1)
If i = 0 Then
Set X = X.Offset(0)
Data.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Copy
DefaultRate.Range("D2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Else:
Data.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Offset(-i).Copy
DefaultRate.Range("D" & 2).Offset(i).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
MyArray(i, 1) = i
MyArray(i, 2) = AWF.RSq(Y, X)
Cells(1 + i, 7).Value = MyArray(i, 1)
Cells(1 + i, 8).Value = MyArray(i, 2)
```

The empty cell produced by the offset function is supposed to be replaced by data from worksheet 2, but I cannot seem to make it work.

Comment: `Range("B" & Rows.Count)` is the very last row of the column/sheet. You want to go `xlUp` from it, not `xlDown`.

Comment: You may want to consider using `DefaultRate.Range("D2") = Data.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)` instead of copy/paste.